# Please analyze my GEMFILE, should ruby-debug be in development only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my GEM file, should 'ruby-debug' be in the development/test block only?

**This is my GEMFILE, I don't have a production block, trying to deploy and things are failing and I can't figure out why.**

Phusion is saying I am missing a source file, but doesn't say which one.   Below is my Gemfile, maybe I need to create a production block with some gem??

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'jquery-rails'



# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
gem 'ruby-debug'


 group :development, :test do

    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'

    gem 'rspec'
    gem 'webrat'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, put ruby-debug in your `group :development, :test` block unless you want to debug in production (and this would just be temporary).

Just as you have to start your development server with a debug flag, passenger also needs to be started with debugging enabled. [Here is a blog post](http://duckpunching.com/passenger-mod_rails-for-development-now-with-debugger) on accomplishing just that in the context of using passenger for development.